# Simple message box homework gives me color wheel

Tags: java, javafx, joptionpane

We did this JavaFX practice problem in class and it keeps giving me a color wheel when I click the "hit me" button. I've looked through the code and even had my professor do so, and I can't see any issues. Is it possible that it's a Mac problem? My friend's code ran just fine on his Windows machine.

```
package csc502_classexample_events_1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
*
* @author aufty
*/
public class CSC502_ClassExample_Events_1 extends Application
{

@Override
public void start(Stage stage)
{
    // Single centered button in HBox
    Button button = new Button("Hit me");
    button.setOnAction(new ClickHandler());
    HBox hBox = new HBox();
    hBox.getChildren().add(button);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    stage.setTitle("My Event Handler Example");
    Scene scene = new Scene(hBox, 400, 80);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    launch(args);
}


}

class ClickHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{

@Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ouch");
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to display a JOptionPane from the FX Application Thread. Swing UI operations should be performed on the AWT event handling thread. In this example, it's particularly bad because the AWT toolkit (probably) hasn't even been initialized.

Something like

```
class ClickHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ouch"));
    }

}
```

should fix it.

(This is Java 8 code, you can use an anonymous inner class for the Runnable instead of the lambda expression if you're still using an old Java version.)

Comment: The worked, but I'm having trouble understanding why my original code was working for my professor and the other student on their Windows machines. I thought it wasn't supposed to make a difference in Java.

Comment: It's platform independent in the sense that the code you originally posted is incorrect whether you run it on either windows or mac. (Just because a piece of code happens to work under some specific circumstances doesn't make it correct.) All UI toolkits need some native implementation behind the scenes; it probably just happens that the native implementation of the UI toolkit for the particular version of the JVM and the particular version of windows that they are using handle this case as a side effect.

Comment: Got it. So that means my professor is teaching me some poor practices. Yikes.

Comment: Yes - that's actually pretty scary to be honest.

Comment: Sideboard: since java8 you can force Swing running on the same event thread - then the sync code is not needed

Comment: I tested the OP's code on Java 8_20 with Mac OS X 10.9.4, and it hung as reported.